# Need help understanding how motors, sensors and other components of a prototype design factor into certifications for industry sale

Tags: stepper-motor, prototyping, manufacturing, production, certification

I have built a prototype and I now need to create a production prototype that I can use as my template for a small 10-15 product unit batch order. I am in the United States where I plan to market first (UL and FCC certs).

My primary point of confusion is around the integration of a 269oz-in NEMA 23 class motor in a production design. My prototype currently integrates an Arduino, a TB6560 motor drive, OLED display, and HC-06 BlueTooth device (w/button press) along with this motor. What I really need help understanding are the following:

1. Custom PCB design or off-the-shelf PLC? What warrants using a PLC? I do not know if it is a viable option considering the other electrical components and functions that are required.
2. If I should design a custom PCB, how do I determine what needs to be re-designed into the board?
3. How do know if my OLED display, HC-06 BlueTooth, or any other selected components jeopardizes obtaining end-product certifications?

I get the feeling that using components like HC-06, which requires 4 quick pin-to-pin wire or solder connections out of the box, seems too good to be true. I greatly appreciate any additional insight into this.

Comment: Your questions are way too broad. Start by getting ideas about packaging, interconnection, shielding, etc from products similar to yours. Then ask more specific questions.

Comment: This question is much too broad and somewhat off the typical electrical engineering design problems asked on this site.. If you plan on selling a product to the public, you should not rely on information off of an online forum where you don't know the qualifications and experience of the responders.. You need to hire a qualified consultant who is familiar with these issues and can offer the proper guidance.

Comment: @Barry Any suggestion on finding such qualified consultants? I can't imagine being in the minority of users on this site looking for some form of guidance beyond prototyping.

Comment: @Mattman944 Well that's precisely what I'm trying to do.. I don't feel confident in determining the packaging of my system if I don't know which sensors and components need to be redesigned into a custom PCB. I have a lot of space for placement, if that clears up any assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

First thing: It would be better to get an EMC consultant first, they can save you time and money (you'll spend somewhere between 2k and 10k USD on a normal product that is subject to IEC61010 and an FCC cert for unintentional radiator)

In the end it really depends on which certs you need. I'm assuming that you'll file as an unintentional radiator for FCC certification (anything with a radio is an intentional radiator). If you do that then you have to list most things that generate any kind of radio, the product needs to be tested to make sure it stays below certain limits.  It is desirable to pass this test the first time around since additional testing costs more. So make sure you do your homework on anything that might generate frequencies in the FCC ranges.

If your device is connected to AC mains it will probably be subject to IEC61010, which means that there are conducted immunity standards (the device can't inject noise back onto the grid, which could happen with switching noise from a motor) and it shouldn't be able to kill anyone with mains voltages.

There are also other saftey and ESD tests that are associated with different products (I don't know all of the standards so I recommend a real expert, get a consultant).